# devMode, phpdotenv variable ignored

Tags: config, multi-environment, environments, configuration, environmentvariables

I'm using dotphpenv for environment specific config.

This works perfectly for my db config. I added another 2 environment vars for `devMode` and `allowAutoUpdates`

```
DEV_MODE=false
AUTO_UPDATE=false
```

and updated `general.php`

```
<?php

return array(

  // Default

  '*' => array(
    ...
    'devMode' => getenv('DEV_MODE'),
    'allowAutoUpdates' => getenv('AUTO_UPDATE'),
    ...
  )
);
```

But with that set, dev mode and auto-update are still available to production.

If I set both to `false` we have no problem. This is obviously a phpdotenv thing because Craft is doing what it's supposed to but if anyone can shed light I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try to echo it from the general.php? `echo getenv('DEV_MODE');`

Comment: I tried `var_dump(getenv('DEV_MODE'));
exit;` inside index.php and it outputs as false there but yeah, ignored by system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `getenv` returns a string (or `false` if the variable is not set, but it is in this case). So you need to cast the string to a boolean value to make it work. However, `(bool)'false'` gives `true`, not `false`. There are two possible solutions:

1. Set the variable to `0` instead of `false` in your `.env` file:

   ```
   DEV_MODE=0
   AUTO_UPDATE=0
   ```

   And then in your config:

   ```
   'devMode' => (bool)getenv('DEV_MODE')
   ```

   This works because `(bool)'0'` gives `false`.
2. Use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775294/parsing-a-string-into-a-boolean-value-in-php/10645030#10645030):

   ```
   'devMode' => filter_var(getenv('DEV_MODE'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
   ```

   This works because the `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` filter returns `TRUE` for `"1"`, `"true"`, `"on"` and `"yes"`, and returns `FALSE` for any other value.